# KDB embedPy use array from Q in Python

Tags: python, arrays, kdb

I am using JupyterQ and have two 2 tables in q:

```
tbl1: ([]month:(1997.01;1997.01;1997.01);
    ric:(3#`GTGS.SI);
    date:(1997.01.06T01:19:21.160;1997.01.06T01:53:57.230;1997.01.06T07:24:19.240);
    price:(0.71;0.72;0.73));

tbl2: ([]month:(1997.01;1997.01;1997.01);
    ric:(3#`NSWF.SI);
    date:(1997.01.06T01:19:21.160;1997.01.06T01:53:57.230;1997.01.06T07:24:19.240);
    price:(0.45;0.46;0.47));
```

I have a class `teCalc` defined in python.

I want to pass to it two arrays as follows (in python):
`teCalc.addObservations(tbl1, tbl2)`

How do I pass those q tables to the class in python?

The following function:

```
print .p.import[`numpy;`:array][tbl1]
```

gives me:

```
{'month': array([1997.01, 1997.01, 1997.01]), 'ric': ['GTGS.SI', 'GTGS.SI', 'GTGS.SI'], 'date': array([-1089.94489398, -1089.92086539, -1089.69144398]), 'price': array([0.71, 0.72, 0.73])}
```

So I can see that it is possible to convert the table in q to a python object.

However, all my attempts to assign it to a variable in python have failed. If I reference either tbl1 or tbl2 in a python line of code in JupyterQ (for example `p)print(tbl1)`) then the tbl1 variable name isn't recognised.

Please do advise. How do I use data from Q on a class created in Python in JupyterQ?

Thanks and regards,

Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[edit]: This should be embedPy not embedQ - my mistake!!

I got this answer from Connor at KX.

The choice is import the data to python using Set or import the python class to Q using Get.

Really cool.

Simon

---

Hi Simon,

Assigning q objects to be accessible from functions defined in the Python side of the API requires you to set the objects. In the case you're describing where you want to run

`p)print(tbl1)`

You would need to run this in the following steps:

```
// Define the q table
mytab:([]5?1f;5?1f)
// set the q table converted to a python dictionary to python variable tbl1
.p.set[`tbl1;mytab]
// Print from the python side of the interface
p)print(tbl1)
```

With regards to calling the class with the q objects you would either need to do the sets from q side to python as above .i.e

```
.p.set[`tbl1;tbl1]
.p.set[`tbl2;tbl2]
p)teCalc.addObservations(tbl1, tbl2)
```

or alternatively 'get' the python callable object and assign it to a q callable function and run directly on the q data without a set

```
// Load the script containing the required class
\l myclass.p
// Retrieve the class
teCalc:.p.get[`teCalc]
// Access the relevant function
addObservations:teCalc[`:addObservations]
// Run on the relevant q data and return result to q (denoted by trailing `)
addObservations[tbl1;tbl2]`
```

It should be noted that when embedPy converts q tables to Python it does so as a list of dictionaries (this is the accurate representation of what a q table is but may be counter intuitive) as such if you need the data to be a pandas dataframe for you use case you may need to do the conversion manually. This is done using 2 functions .ml.tab2df/.ml.df2tab which are both available within the Kx Machine learning toolkit [here](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fkxsystems%2Fml&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNFpYF0u61E_TYMoLonSJHWU126aXA).

More information on embedPy is available at the below links which outline in detail all of the above

https://code.kx.com/q/ml/embedpy/userguide/

https://code.kx.com/q/ml/embedpy/faq/

All the best,

Conor